# Mock server Request

Tags: java, spring, servlets, junit

Im using spring, and in my controller method im expecting a query paramether

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public MyClass myMethod(
            @ApiParam(defaultValue = "some string", value = "some text") @RequestParam("myParam") MyClass2 myParam) {
            //do something
        }
```

now in JUnit test i want to call this method, for this i have prepeared a request, however i can not find a proper way to `setQueryString()`

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.setRequestURI("/pathToMyMethod");
request.setQueryString(new MyClass2().toString());
```

Constructing a new object and calling `toString()` on it does not work.
(calling empty constructor is creating object with random values)

Failure trace:
`org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MyClass2 parameter 'myParam' is not present.`

How to create such request properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html).

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/").param("myParam", "paramValue"))
     .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: i'm trying this way but it indicates error ``The method params(String, String) is undefined for the type ResultActions``

Comment: Oops. My bad. `param` is invoked after `get("/")`.

Comment: btw. is there method simmilar to ``.param()`` to pass URI paramethers?

Comment: Basically, you just say something like `get("/{id}", 5)`.